# temporary value dropped while borrowed and cannot resolve

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am trying to sending data to an API endpoint and running into some borrowing issuess

Code

```rust
#[post("/send")]
async fn send(field: web::Json<Region>, data: web::Data<Datum>) -> impl Responder {
    let address = data.address;
    let provider = Provider::try_from(&data.provider).unwrap();
    let provider = Arc::new(provider);
    let coordinate = Coordinate::new(address, provider);
    let response = coordinate
        .method::<_, (Vec<U256>, U256)>("send", (field.region, field.price))
        .unwrap()
        .send()
        .await;

    HttpResponse::Created()
        .content_type(ContentType::json())
        .body(response.unwrap().to_string())
}
```

Error

```bash
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
   --> app/src/main.rs:132:14
    |
132 |       let response = land_contract
    |  ______________^
133 | |         .method::<_, (Vec<U256>, U256)>("send", (field.region, field.price))
134 | |         .unwrap()
    | |_________________^ creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
135 |           .send()
136 |           .await;
    |                 - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
...
141 |   }
    |   - borrow might be used here, when `tx` is dropped and runs the destructor`
    |
    = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value

error[E0507]: cannot move out of dereference of `Json<Region>`
   --> app/src/main.rs:133:50
    |
133 |         .method::<_, (Vec<U256>, U256)>("send", (field.region, field.price))
    |                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Vec<U256>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Comment: Can you add the signatures of `method` and `send`? It looks like `method` returns a `Result<T, Err>` and `send` takes a `&T`. If that's the case, you'll need to do what the compiler suggests: stash what `method` returns in a variable before calling `send` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .method::<_, (Vec, U256)>("send", (field.region, field.price))
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Vec<U256>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

The error is that `field.region` is a `Vec<U256>` which doesn't implement a Copy trait. Since that's the case, the compiler is trying to move the value out as mentioned in the error `cannot move out of dereference of` Json`. One way to fix this issue is cloning the value of` field.region`.

```
.method::<_, (Vec<U256>, U256)>("send", (field.region.clone(), field.price))
```

You might have to do similar cloning for `field.price` also.

The other error is regarding temporary value being created at `.unwrap()`. Since you are using `await`. It will wait for the future to complete but the value created with `unwrap()` gets dropped as it is not bound to any local variable so you get this error.

Break the code into 2 lines to solve this error with help of a local binding.

```
let response = coordinate
        .method::<_, (Vec<U256>, U256)>("send", (field.region, field.price))
        .unwrap();
response.send().await;
```